# dplyr lag has a problem with integer64 from bit64

Tags: r, dplyr, bit64

`dplyr::lag` works fine with integers with the first entry being `<NA>`, but with `bit64::integer64` the first entry is a huge number.

This is my setting:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
#> ...
library(bit64)
#> Loading required package: bit
#> Attaching package bit
#> ...
#> Attaching package bit64
#> ...
#> The following object is masked from 'package:bit':
#> 
#>     still.identical
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     :, %in%, is.double, match, order, rank
library(reprex)
sessionInfo()
#> R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
#> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0 (64-bit)
#> Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
#> 
#> ...     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#>  [1] reprex_0.3.0    bit64_0.9-7     bit_1.1-14      magrittr_1.5   
#>  [5] forcats_0.4.0   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_0.8.1     purrr_0.3.2    
#>  [9] readr_1.3.1     tidyr_0.8.3     tibble_2.1.3    ggplot2_3.2.0  
#> [13] tidyverse_1.2.1
#> 
#> ...
```

Here is a minimal reprex:

```
tib_int64 <- tibble(A_int   = as.integer(c(1,2,3)),
                    A_int64 = as.integer64(c(1,2,3)))

tib_int64 %>% mutate(B = lag(A_int), C = lag(A_int64))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   A_int A_int64     B C                  
#>   <int> <int64> <int> <int64>            
#> 1     1 1          NA 9218868437227407266
#> 2     2 2           1                   1
#> 3     3 3           2                   2
```

The first entry in the `C` column should be `<NA>` like in the `B` column.
Is this a `dplyr` problem or a `bit64` problem?
This is not too difficult to work around, but shouldn't this be filed as a bug?

Comment: What happens if you set the argument `default = NA_integer64_`?

Comment: @mikeck Thanks, that solves it nicely.  The question is still should this be considered a bug?

Comment: yeah I think it's worth posting an issue on their GitHub page, seems like it should be an easy fix.

Comment: @mikeck Thanks.  Bug reported and taken care of in [tidyverse/dplyr](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4558)